# IllegalArgumentException thrown when count and collect function in spark

Tags: python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.6

I tried to load a small dataset on local Spark when this exception is thrown when I used `count()` in PySpark (`take()` seems working). I tried to search about this issue but got no luck in figuring out why. It seems something is wrong with the partition of RDD. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
sc.stop()
sc = SparkContext("local[4]", "temp")
testfile1 = sc.textFile(localpath('part-00000-Copy1.xml'))
testfile1.filter(lambda x: x.strip().encode('utf-8').startswith(b'<row')).take(1) ## take function seems working
```

and this is what the data looks like:

```
['  <row AcceptedAnswerId="15" AnswerCount="5" Body="&lt;p&gt;How should I elicit prior distributions from experts when fitting a Bayesian model?&lt;/p&gt;&#10;" CommentCount="1" CreationDate="2010-07-19T19:12:12.510" FavoriteCount="17" Id="1" LastActivityDate="2010-09-15T21:08:26.077" OwnerUserId="8" PostTypeId="1" Score="26" Tags="&lt;bayesian&gt;&lt;prior&gt;&lt;elicitation&gt;" Title="Eliciting priors from experts" ViewCount="1457" />']
```

this is the problem:

```
test1 = testfile1.filter(lambda x: (x.strip().encode('utf-8').startswith(b'<row'))).filter(lambda x: x is not None)
test1.count()
```

here is the exception:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-d7626ed81f56> in <module>()
----> 1 test1.count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)
   1039         3
   1040         """
-> 1041         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1042 
   1043     def stats(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in sum(self)
   1030         6.0
   1031         """
-> 1032         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1033 
   1034     def count(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    904         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    905         # to the final reduce call
--> 906         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    907         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    908 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2068)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~
Update:
So I tried to create a minimal example in PySpark, and the issue of `count()` still exists. I was wondering if this issue is related to the configuration of Spark in my jupyter notebook. Here's a minimal example:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
import findspark
findspark.init()
import random
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="Pi")
num_samples = 100000000
def inside(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return x*x + y*y < 1
sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).take(10)
```

And here's the output:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

And do the `count()` again:

```
sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()
```

And the output looks similar to the previous example:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-5588c6957b1d> in <module>()
----> 1 sc.parallelize(range(0, num_samples)).filter(inside).count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)
   1039         3
   1040         """
-> 1041         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1042 
   1043     def stats(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in sum(self)
   1030         6.0
   1031         """
-> 1032         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1033 
   1034     def count(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    904         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    905         # to the final reduce call
--> 906         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    907         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    908 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2068)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

One thing that I noticed is that when I run PySpark over jupyter notebook, the terminal shows some WARNING:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
18/01/15 14:05:35 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

And a google search revealed this [post](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-ubuntu-pyspark-231c45677de0) talked about the last WARNING.

Comment: What is the Spark version? Is this full Java traceback? Also this `.filter(lambda x: x is not None)` doesn't make sense - if input was ever `None` (won't be if input comes from `textFile`) it would fail on `(lambda x: (x.strip()....`

Comment: The spark version is `2.2.1`. and Yes, this is all the java traceback. Yes you are right, but if i switch these two filters, it still gave the same error.

Comment: Id' recommend removing it then and in general reducing this to a [mcve]. If for example `testfile1.filter(lambda x: True).count()` or even `testfile1.count()` produce the same error then code itself is irrelevant and is only confusing. Also, why do you call `sc.stop()`? Have you tried executing this with clean application without recreating the context? And once again - if you determine it is not relevant, just removed it and reduce the code. I'd also recommend reducing input and checking if it solves the problem.

Comment: I ran your example as is, with the single record you provided and it worked. Used Spark 2.2.1. Could this be sensitive to your data? If so, you may need to post some more records for us to replicate.

Answer (score 13):

Are you using Java 9? There are so many issues using Java9 with Apache projects now.

If that is the case and this is a Mac OS, do the following:

```
cd /usr/libexec
./java_home -V
```

And you will be able to see the java versions you have. Pick up an older version as your new `JAVA_HOME`.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.{YourVersion}.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

If this works (I am not sure because information is missing), add the `export` command to your profile init script.

Comment: I have had the very same issue when using Spark 2.3.0 together with the JDK 10 - reverting back to Java 8 resolved it

Comment: I have both Java 8 and Java 10 installed. But i am using java 8 for my JAVA_HOME still cannot

Comment: Then i uninstall my Java 10 and restarted my Spyder IDE. It works!!

Comment: This issue occurred for me on both Spark 2.2.0 and 2.2.2. Only reverting from JDK 10 to JDK 8 helped.

Answer (score 4):

Had this trouble for 3 hours and in the end,
What worked for me is to switch to Spark 2.2.0 instead of Spark 2.2.1,
Give it a try.