# IllegalArgumentException with Spark collect() on Jupyter

Tags: pyspark, jupyter, python-3.6

I have a setup with Jupyter 4.3.0, Python 3.6.3 (Anaconda), and PySpark 2.2.1.

The following example will fail when run through Jupyter:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

rdd = sc.parallelize(['A','B','C'])
rdd.collect()
```

Below is the complete stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-0d4a2ca9edf4> in <module>()
      2 
      3 rdd = sc.parallelize(['A','B','C'])
----> 4 rdd.collect()

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    807         """
    808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    811 

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2068)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:467)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

The same example runs successfully using the pyspark client. It also runs successfully (in either Jupyter or the pyspark client) when using `take()` instead of `collect()`.

Any ideas of what might be going on? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243877/illegalargumentexception-thrown-when-count-and-collect-function-in-spark) suggests it could be some bug in Spark 2.2.1. I'd rather not downgrade to Spark 2.2.0 as suggested if at all possible.

**UPDATE:** I'm running on macOS High Sierra (10.13.3). Here is the output of `sc._conf.getAll()`:

```
[('spark.sql.catalogImplementation', 'hive'),
 ('spark.app.id', 'local-1517752276379'),
 ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
 ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
 ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
 ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
 ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
 ('spark.driver.port', '55920'),
 ('spark.app.name', 'pyspark-shell'),
 ('spark.driver.host', '192.168.1.5')]
```

And here are some further Jupyter-PySpark integration configuration:

`~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py`

```
import os
import sys
spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
if not spark_home:
    raise ValueError('SPARK_HOME environment variable is not set')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip'))
exec(open(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py')).read())
```

`~/Library/Jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json`

```
{
    "display_name": "PySpark (Spark 2.2.1)",
    "language": "python",
    "argv": [
        "/Users/rodrygo/anaconda3/bin/python3",
        "-m",
        "ipykernel",
        "--profile=pyspark",
        "-f",
        "{connection_file}"
    ],
    "env": {
        "CAPTURE_STANDARD_OUT": "true",
        "CAPTURE_STANDARD_ERR": "true",
        "SEND_EMPTY_OUTPUT": "false",
        "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/"
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to run the same code properly on my spark 2.2.1 on jupyter notebook. Might be a problem with spark configuration. Can you add the configuration of the jupyter notebook sc._conf.getAll()

Comment: @pratiklodha Please have a look at the info you requested. I've also included the contents of the config files I used to integrate a PySpark kernel into Jupypter.

Answer (score 12):

For those of you having the same problem, there seems to be an issue with Spark (as of version 2.2.1) and Java 9. I got my example code to work by setting JAVA_HOME back to Java 1.8.

Comment: Ya, I had the similar kind of problem, when I changed my java version to 1.8, It started working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: java -version 

    java version "1.8.0_192"


    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)


    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)

but I am still facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when loading text files. Apache Spark does not work with Java >= 9 yet. Switch back to Java 8.
Remove your current Java SDK with these commands:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java
sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk(your version here)
```

Then download [JAVA SDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and install it. You should be good.

Comment: A link for a reference regarding `Apache Spark does not work with Java >= 9 yet` would be good?

Comment: @TDP sorry, do not have official reference. I had the same issue and I google it, found some one with same issue also, see [here](https://gist.github.com/lukewang1024/659ec27847169086dde8677e25156573). I uninstalled Java 10 and reinstalled Java 8. Works perfect.